# How can I use computed property to bind for a field inside a data table?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

1) Using computed property to create a currency mask for a normal text field. I get this working.

**Template**

```
<v-text-field  :prefix="currency" v-model="initialBalanceFormatted" label="Initial Balance" :disabled="disabled"></v-text-field>
```

**Code**

```
get initialBalanceFormatted(){
    return this.formatAsCurrency(this.loan.initialBalance, 0)
}

set initialBalanceFormatted(newValue: any) {
    this.loan.initialBalance = Number(newValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
}
```

2) How can I use the computed property for a field inside data table?

**Template**

```
<v-data-table v-bind:headers="headerLoanBalance" :items="loan.loanBalances" hide-actions="" :total-items="disableSorting">
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr>
           <td class="pl-0">
             <v-text-field :prefix="currency" v-model="loanbalance[props.item.value]" :disabled="disabled"></v-text-field>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

**Code**

```
get loanbalance() {
    return this.formatAsCurrency(props.item.value, 0)
}
set loanbalance(newValue: any) {
    props.item.value = Number(newValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide codePen ?

Comment: @Toodoo https://codepen.io/veer3383/pen/gzNdeW?editors=1011